# Запись данных в бд из post запроса

Tags: php, mysql, база-данных, post

Здравствуйте.
Как записать данные в бд из post запроса? 
Есть такой код:

```
<?php
if( !empty($_POST))
{
$data = $_POST; // в $data мы получим переданные данные
// сохраняем данные в БД или куда-нибудь еще    
}
?>
```

Сейчас он записывает данные в файл json, и выглядят они так:

Так мы получаем данные из post запроса, теперь надо в БД по $utm_source найти запись, и к полю install прибавить 1, а к полю profit прибавить то что будет в переменной $profit

```
$data = $_POST;
preg_match("|"profit":"(.*)"|sei", $data, $profit);
preg_match("|"utm_source":"(.*)"|sei", $data, $utm_source);
preg_match("|"utm_medium":"(.*)"|sei", $data, $utm_medium);
```

Проблема в том что я не очень силен в mySQL, помогите создать запрос который бы делал написанное выше.

Заранее извиняюсь если где-то написал не точно или не верно.

Comment: Вы хотябы попытайтесь! Это плохая практика расчитывать на простое копирование готового кода.

Comment: Пробовал, но код почему то не шел, можно хотя бы ссылку на информацию которая может помочь, дельного не чего не нашел, или плохо искал.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Вы задаете вопрос, охватывающий несколько технологий, вместе с тем на базовом уровне, и просите решить конкретную задачу. Возможно, поэтому вы не можете найти ответ, а ваш вопрос здесь минусуют. Попробуйте разбить свой вопрос на несколько, и искать ответ на них, а потом объединить полученную информацию.
Что касается базы данных, можете начать например отсюда: [w3 schools - php mysql insert](http://www.w3schools.com/php/php_mysql_insert.asp)

Здесь можете найти пример работы с json: http://www.kodingmadesimple.com/2014/12/how-to-insert-json-data-into-mysql-php.html

> Пробовал, но код почему то не шел

Имеет смысл копировать в вопрос свой соответствующий код, и разбираться, что надо исправить в нем =)

Comment: Извините за такую большую задержку, отредактировал вопрос и добавил код который не работает.